# Training Loss Improving but Validation Converges Early

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, convergence

I am creating a CNN using TensorFlow and when training, I find that the training dataset is still improving (i.e. loss still decreasing), while the test/validation dataset has converged and is no longer improving. (Learning Curve Plot attached below)

Does anyone know why this might be the case and how could I possibly fix it, to have the validation loss reduce along with the training? Would be greatly appreciated!

Plot of my models learning curve:

[image]

Comment: Show your code...

Comment: Your MSE is already very low for both training and validation. It is overfitting but very slightly as the MSE for the training is `~0.001` and the MSE for the validation set is `~0.0015`. You could implement regularization to overcome this but I find the model good as it is. An MSE of `0` is considered to be a perfect model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this means you're hitting your architecture's limit, training loss will keep decreasing (this is known as overfitting), which will eventually INCREASE validation loss, make changes to the parameters or consider altering your layers (adding, removing, etc.), maybe even look into ways you could alter the dataset.

when this happened to me a while ago I added a LSTM layer to my CNN architecture and also incorporated K-means validation, this is not a walkthrough, you need to figure this out for your specific problem, good luck.

Comment: So would it negatively affect my model's prediction if I leave the NN to further overfit? As in, should I also reduce the number of epochs to the point where the validation set converges? Thanks for the help!

Comment: yes, that's the point
one way of doing this is by saving the changes in the model only if the validation loss decreases over the epoch, however, there are many ways that are much better at doing this

Answer (score 1):

The plot of losses is very typical. Your model appears to be performing very well with very low MSE losss. At this point you have essentially reached the limits of your models performance. One thing which may help is to use an adjustable learning rate. The Keras callback ReduceLROnPlateau can be setup to monitor the validation loss. If the validation loss fails to decrease for a 'patience' number of epochs the learning rate will be reduced by a factor "factor" where factor is a number less than 1. Documentation is [here.](https://keras.io/api/callbacks/reduce_lr_on_plateau/)
You may also want to use the Keras EarlyStopping callback. This callback can be set to monitor validation loss and halt training if it fails to decrease for "patience" number of epochs. If you set restore_best_weights=True it will leave your model with the weights used in the epoch with the lowest validation loss. This will prevent your model from returning an over fit model. My recommended code is shown below

```
rlronp=f.keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor="val_loss", factor=0.5, patience=1)
    

estop=tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor="val_loss",patience=3,restore_best_weights=True)
callbacks=[rlronp, estop]
```

In model.fit include callbacks=callbacks. I suspect neither of the above will provide much improvement. You will probably have to try some changes to your model as well. Adding a Dropout layer may help to some degree to reduce over-fitting as would including regularization. Documentation for that is [here.](https://keras.io/api/layers/regularizers/). Of course the standard approach of getting a larger data set may also help but is not always easy to achieve. If you are working with images you could try image augmentation using say the Keras ImageDataGenerator or Tensorflow Image Augmentation layers. Documentation for that is [here.](https://keras.io/api/layers/preprocessing_layers/image_preprocessing/). One thing I found which helps for the case of images is to crop your images to just the Region of Interest (ROI). For example if you were doing face recognition cropping the images to just be of the face will help significantly.

Comment: I was doing something similar by manually re-compiling and fitting the model, using a lower LR. But now thinking about it, would it not lead to the model overfitting (whether I use ReduceLROnPlateau or use manually change the LR)? Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: eventually the model would over fit. That is why I included the early stop callback. With the reduce learning rate callback you can start with a larger learning rate and have the model converge faster than using a very small learning rate.